# What algorithm is used when using the in operator in python to search a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, operators

When using the 'in' operator to search for an item in a list e.g.

```
if item in list:
  print item
```

What algorithm is used to search for this item. Is it a straight search of the list from beginning to end or does it use something like binary search?

Comment: `in`, iterates over items in order, there's no search

Comment: @RC. : True for `list`s, of course. But not true for other containers (Sets use a hash table, for example - see `set_contains_entry()` in [setobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05274ab06182/Objects/setobject.c) line 689.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`list`s can't be assumed to be in sorted order (or any order at all), so binary search won't work. Nor can the keys be assumed to be hashable, so unlike a `dict` or `set` a hash-table lookup can't be used to accelerate the search

At a guess it's a straight-through check of every element from first to last.

I'll try and dig up the relevant Python source code.

--

Edit: The Python `list.__contains__()` function, which implements the `in` operator, is defined in [listobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05274ab06182/Objects/listobject.c):

```
   393 static int
   394 list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
   395 {
   396     Py_ssize_t i;
   397     int cmp;
   398 
   399     for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
   400         cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
   401                                            Py_EQ);
   402     return cmp;
   403 }
```

It iterates over every element in the list, from the first element to the last element (or until it finds a match.) No shortcuts here.

--

Edit 2: The plot thickens. If Python detects that you're testing for membership of an element in a **constant** `list` or `set`, like:

```
if letter in ['a','e','i','o','u']:    # list version
if letter in {'a','e','i','o','u'}:    # set version
```

Edit 3 [@JohnMachin]:

The constant list is optimised to a constant **tuple** in 2.5-2.7 and 3.1-3.3.
The constant set is optimised to a (constant) frozenset in 3.3.

See also @CoryCarson's answer.

Comment: The constant list is optimised to a constant **tuple** in 2.5-2.7 and 3.1-3.3

Comment: @JohnMachin: So not a hash-table lookup for purposes of the `in` operator? Feel free to edit my answer for accuracy.

Answer (score 6):

If `list` is a literal list, Python 3.2+ will take a faster approach: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations

Comment: Oh, very nice. Just to be clear, that particular change note appears to be talking about converting constant `set`s to `frozenset`s - I think the optimisation for constant `list`s predates that.